# Can connect through terminal ssh, but vscode can't connect and keeps trying again

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server, vscode-remote-ssh

I can use the terminal ssh to connect to the server, but when I use vscode to connect, it keep retrying, the following is the specific log information

```
[11:58:27.331] Log Level: 2
[11:58:27.392] VS Code version: 1.77.3
[11:58:27.392] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.100.0
[11:58:27.393] win32 x64
[11:58:27.519] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+lab4", attempt 1
[11:58:27.521] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[11:58:27.522] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:58:27.524] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"222.201.145.200":"linux","lab_server3":"linux","lab3":"linux","lab2":"linux","lab8":"linux","lab4":"linux","222.201.144.173":"linux","lab3090":"linux"}
[11:58:27.524] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[11:58:27.525] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[11:58:27.525] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[11:58:27.526] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[11:58:27.527] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[11:58:27.527] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[11:58:27.528] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:58:27.529] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[11:58:27.529] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[11:58:27.530] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": false
[11:58:27.531] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[11:58:27.532] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[11:58:27.532] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[11:58:27.546] SSH Resolver called for host: lab4
[11:58:27.546] Setting up SSH remote "lab4"
[11:58:27.556] Using commit id "704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710" and quality "stable" for server
[11:58:27.583] Install and start server if needed
[11:58:27.606] Checking ssh with "D:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.627] Got error from ssh: spawn D:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.629] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.639] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.640] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.654] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.655] Checking ssh with "D:\program\java\jre\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.665] Got error from ssh: spawn D:\program\java\jre\bin\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.666] Checking ssh with "D:\program\java\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.675] Got error from ssh: spawn D:\program\java\bin\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.676] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.685] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.686] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.699] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.700] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.715] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.716] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.725] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.726] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.736] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:58:27.738] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[11:58:27.997] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[11:58:28.023] Running script with connection command: "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -o ClearAllForwardings=true lab4 bash
[11:58:28.055] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:58:31.249] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:58:31.251] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[11:58:31.256] > cc98a819b4e3: running
[11:58:31.341] > Acquiring lock on /home/wyq/.vscode-server/bin/704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1
> cff4710/vscode-remote-lock.wyq.704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
> Found existing installation at /home/wyq/.vscode-server/bin/704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342
> c436f1ede30d1cff4710...
> Checking /home/wyq/.vscode-server/.704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710.log 
> and /home/wyq/.vscode-server/.704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710.pid for a
>  running server
> Looking for server with pid: 31697
[11:58:31.379] > Found running server...
[11:58:31.386] > 
> *
> * Visual Studio Code Server
> *
> * By using the software, you agree to
> * the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-lice
> nse) and
> * the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacyst
> atement).
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 39963 with wget
[11:58:32.411] > failed: No route to host.
> cc98a819b4e3: start  
> exitCode==28==       
> listeningOn==39963== 
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==       
> tmpDir==/tmp==       
> platform==linux==    
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> cc98a819b4e3: end
[11:58:32.412] Received install output:   
exitCode==28==       
listeningOn==39963== 
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==       
tmpDir==/tmp==       
platform==linux==    
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====

[11:58:32.413] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[11:58:32.448] > 
[11:58:33.425] Running script with connection command: "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -o ClearAllForwardings=true lab4 bash
[11:58:33.432] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:58:33.976] "install" terminal command done
[11:58:33.977] Install terminal quit with output: 
[11:58:34.010] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:58:34.011] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[11:58:34.178] > cc98a819b4e3: running
[11:58:34.256] > Acquiring lock on /home/wyq/.vscode-server/bin/704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1
> cff4710/vscode-remote-lock.wyq.704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
[11:58:34.301] > Found existing installation at /home/wyq/.vscode-server/bin/704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342
> c436f1ede30d1cff4710...
> Checking /home/wyq/.vscode-server/.704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710.log 
> and /home/wyq/.vscode-server/.704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710.pid for a
>  running server
> Looking for server with pid: 31697
[11:58:34.326] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Visual Studio Code Server
> *
> * By using the software, you agree to
> * the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-lice
> nse) and
> * the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacyst
> atement).
> *
> 
[11:58:34.381] > Checking server status on port 39963 with wget
[11:58:35.354] > failed: No route to host.
> cc98a819b4e3: start  
> exitCode==28==       
> listeningOn==39963== 
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==       
> tmpDir==/tmp==       
> platform==linux==    
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> cc98a819b4e3: end
[11:58:35.355] Received install output:   
exitCode==28==       
listeningOn==39963== 
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==       
tmpDir==/tmp==       
platform==linux==    
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====
```

I checked the log file of vscode-server, the information is as follows:

```
*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* By using the software, you agree to
* the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
* the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
*
Server bound to 127.0.0.1:39963 (IPv4)
Extension host agent listening on 39963

[11:56:26]

[11:56:26] Extension host agent started.
[11:56:28] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mobile.events.data.microsoft.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'mobile.events.data.microsoft.com'
}
Last EH closed, shutting down
[12:01:26] Last EH closed, shutting down
```

I don't know why this problem occurs

1. I tried to delete the whole .vscode-server and reconnect, but it didn't solve the problem
2. I killed all processes about vscode and reconnected, it didn't work（`pkill -9 vscode`）